# Why does "zum" translate here as "about the"?

Tags: translation, preposition, dative

> Sie hat eine Frage **zum** Telefon.

Here the sentence translates to

> She had a question **about the** telephone.

But *zum* (zu + dem) means "to the". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sie hat eine Frage zum **T**elefon.

Prepositions never match between languages, not even between closely related ones as English and German. While English *about* often translates as *über*, it translates as much as often as *zu* or *von*. These are all valid and have the same meaning:

> Erzähl mir etwas über dich.
>
> Erzähl mir etwas von dir.
>
> Erzähl mir etwas zu dir.

The preposition needed is commanded by the verb phrase. For *eine Frage haben* and the meaning *about*, it's *zu*, because the phrase

> Sie hat eine Frage über das Telefon.

means

*She has a question, she's on the phone.*

Comment: To me, the sentence «Sie hat eine Frage über das Telefon» carries as well the meaning that the question is about the phone.

Comment: "Sie hat eine Frage über das Telefon" is somewhat ambiguous. But "Ich habe darüber eine Frage" is unusual, "Ich habe dazu eine Frage" is the usual way to say "I have a question about that".

Comment: Is then there a list of which preposition to use in which case? I know here exists a list on dative and accusative preposition but that's it. I didn't know the verb affected the preposition. Is there a list or is it something that is gained by experience.

Comment: It's not adviseable learning the prepositions separately, you should learn them along with the verbs/verb phrases. Any good dictionary will list verbs along with the prepositions they can go with, and the different meanings.